How to handle fast Kafka offset consumption vs. slow join and sink in PyFlink with savepoints?
I’m working with PyFlink to process two Kafka streams, join them, and then output to a third Kafka stream. My goal is to enable graceful exits with exactly-once semantics by creating savepoints and then restoring the state on restart. However, I’m encountering an issue with my current setup:
Problem: When running the job, Kafka offsets are consumed very quickly, but the join and sink operations are much slower. As a result, when I attempt to trigger a savepoint and exit, the savepoint includes a high Kafka offset, but very few joined records have been processed and written to the sink.
Issue on Restart: When restarting from the savepoint, the job resumes with the latest Kafka offset from the savepoint. Because few records were actually joined and output, a significant portion of the original data is missing in the downstream sink.
Goal: I need to ensure that processing rates are balanced so that more joined records make it to the sink before I
exit. I suspect that backpressure could help slow down Kafka offset consumption and balance the processing.
Has anyone encountered this before? Is backpressure the correct approach here, or are there better ways to ensure Kafka offset consumption matches join/sink speeds in PyFlink? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Using 2 Kafka Streams as input, reading them via TableAPI environment, joining them on the fly, then outputting to another kafka stream.
We attempted to use a savepoint to stop the job gracefully and restart it using the savepoint. However, when trying to restore the script from Savepoint getting the following error: "UserVisible tail should not be larger than offset. This is a bug"
When I am monitoring Kafka Offsets via Offset Explorer, I see that almost all messages have been consumed, but messages that were actually joined were very very less.
We also tried using checkpointing, but upon restarting the job, some data was missing.

I think you'll need to include your code and configuration information in this question. The most likely explanation for the behavior you're seeing is a badly configured Flink workflow, or incorrect user functions, so without more details it's hard to diagnose.
